# How to print "\\/" symbol described below in java?

Tags: java

I want to print `"\\/"` this symbol in java. I tried using `System.out.println("\\/")` but it didn't show the first `"\"`. Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: `System.out.println("\\/")`

Comment: You need to escape it the proper way. Try "\\/"

Comment: You need to escape the slash using another "\", so use `System.out.println("\\/")`

Comment: Are you trying to print `"\/"` or ```"\\/"``` ?

Comment: Based on the text from the question (need to be edited properly), he need to print `\\/` so `"\\\\/"` but that's the same problem.